# Возможно ли присвоить результат new не указателю?

Tags: c++, указатели, конструктор, преобразование

Насколько мне известно, результат выполнения new нужно присваивать указателю, т.е.:

```
T t = new T(); //должна быть ошибка. Несоответствие типов т.к. new возвращает указатель
T *t = new T(); // Правильный вариант
```

Однако, необъяснимым для меня образом, следующий код делает первый вариант возможным. Причем только для одного конечного класса C1. Если попытаться сделать подобное с другим C2, появляется ошибка. Причем если упростить конструктор (убрать список инициализации и аргументы), то все будет работать по-обычному.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
private:
    int id;
    static int instrumentsCount;
    static int lastId;
public:
    A();
    virtual ~A() = 0;
};
class B:public A
{
private:
    int field1;
public:
    B(int arg):A(),field1(arg) {std::cout<<"B\n";}
};
class C1:public B
{
private:
    const bool field2;
public:
    C1(bool o = true):B(170),field2(o){std::cout<<"C1\n";}
    ~C1();
};
class C2:public B
{
private:
    const int field3;
public:
    C2(int d = 20):B(120),field3(d){std::cout<<"C2\n";}
    ~C2();
};
int A::instrumentsCount = 0;
int A::lastId = 0;
A::A()
{
    this->id = A::lastId++;
    A::instrumentsCount++;
    std::cout<<"A "<<this->id<<" created\n";
}
A::~A()
{
    std::cout<<"A "<<this->id<<" destroyed\n";
    A::instrumentsCount--;
}
C1::~C1(){}
C2::~C2(){}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    C1 c1 = new C1(true);
    C2 *c2 = new C2(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Как результат выводится следующее:

```
A 0 created
B
C1
A 1 created
B
C1
A 2 created
B
C2
A 1 destroyed
```

Что в принципе логично, но почему конструктор базового класса A вызывается при создании C1 два раза? Прошу открыть мне глаза на мои ошибки( Использую QT Creator 5.9

Comment: Именно во избежание такого рода неожиданностей придуман спецификатор `explicit`. Старайтесь объявлять ваши конструкторы с одним параметром как `explicit`, если вы не вводили их специально для выполнения неявных преобразований. В данном случае: `explicit C1(bool o = true)...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имеется фундаментальный тип, для которого вы можете написать выражение

```
T t = new T();
```

Таким типом является фундаментальный тип `bool`.

```
bool b = new bool();
```

Если инициализатор отличен от нуля, то переменная получает значение `true` , в противном случае значение `false`.

Из стандарта C++ (4.14 Boolean conversions)

> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, **pointer**, or
>   pointer to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A
>   zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is
>   converted to false; any other value is converted to true. For
>   direct-initialization (8.6), a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type bool; the resulting value is false.

Однако такой код ведет к утечке памяти, так как значение указателя на выделенную память теряется.

В примере кода из вашего вопроса в классе `C1` имеется конструктор преобразования

```
C1(bool o = true):B(170),field2(o){std::cout<<"C1\n";}
```

Параметр этого класса имеет тип `bool`, а переданный в качестве аргумента указатель может неявно быть преобразован в тип `bool`.

Answer (score 2):

Да все не просто просто, а очень просто:

```
C1 c1 = new C1(true);
```

Итак, создается новый `C1`, указатель на который используется как инициализатор для конструирования `c1`. Есть конструктор `C1(bool)`, который и использован.

Имеем - созданный в динамической памяти `C1`, потерянный (утечка памяти), так как ненулевое значение указателя просто неявно преобразовано в `bool` для вызова *второго* конструктора - конструктора, который создает  `c1`...

Что логично - вы же создаете **два** объекта `C1`.

Answer (score 0):

Моё дополнение не совсем по теме, но может быть кому-то полезно. Результат, возвращённый оператором `new` (или функцией `malloc`) можно присвоить целому числу, но нужно использовать приведение типов:

```
uint32_t a = (uint32_t)malloc(5);
```

Тогда в переменную `a` попадёт адрес участка памяти, выраженный целым числом. В рядовых программах так делать не рекомендуется, но если вы работаете напрямую с железом, это может быть полезно. Например, это число можно будет записать в регистр контроллера DMA.

Comment: К чему это здесь - не совсем понятно, но ясно, что на 64-битной платформе "адрес участка памяти" в переменную типа `uint32_t` никак не поместится. Специально для таких целей существует тип `uintptr_t`.

Comment: А ещё вместо C-style cast использовать reinterpret_cast. Он лучше передаёт намерение сконвертировать один тип в совершенно другой.

Comment: А ещё я где-то встречал, что для преобразования указателя с целое и обратно использовался union с двумя полями - целым и указателем.